# setState only updating SOME values

Tags: reactjs

I have the following setState function in my code...

```
this.setState(
  (prev,props)=>{
    if(prev.qsRemaining===1){this.deActivateDJM();}
    if(prev.qsRemaining>0){
      let newQs = prev.qsRemaining-1
      console.log("Decrementing qsRemaining to:", newQs );
      return {
        qsRemaining: newQs,
        canary:"Tweet!",
      }
    }
  },
  ()=>{ console.log("qsRemaining is now:", this.state.qsRemaining ); }
);
```

The first log shows the correctly decremented value of 19, down from the initial value of 20. The second log, in theory run after setState has concluded, shows the original value of 20. Looking at this.state later on I can see "canary" has been added to the state object but qsRemaining remains set to 20.

There is only one other place in my code where anything is assigned to qsRemaining and it is definitely not being called at any point during or after the above.

After googling around I have made sure I have a full and correct constructor at the start of my class but that has made no difference.

I am beyond confused. Either the value isn't getting set, or something is resetting it but I feel like I've eliminated both of those possibilities. I am stuck. Can anybody recommend where/how/what to check next?

Comment: Here is an online example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/decrease-remaining-number?file=index.js. Maybe you can compare and decide what is going wrong for you. I feel like you should reconsider moving `this. deActivateDJM` call out of your `setState` call since it looks like a side effect of the user behavior (I guess).

Comment: @HilmiErdemKEREN Thanks but that example doesn't work. Also deActivateDJM could potentially have side effects but it isn't actually called until the number is decremented to 1. I can't get it to decrement at all.

Comment: Please check the console in the example. It decreases from 20 to 0 one by one when you click on the button. It logs the state every time as well. I just called the decrease after state change to automate button click. Isn’t that what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @HilmiErdemKEREN Actually it has a bug. It jumps from 20 to zero on the first click and then decrements by one (going into the negative numbers) on subsequent clicks. I have tried it on a Linux and a Windows box and on Firefox and Chromium/Chrome.

Comment: @HilmiErdemKEREN Ahh I see now, it recurses down to zero in the decrement routine. If I take that line out it decrements by 1 with each click. Thanks.

Comment: I'm happy to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out to be async issue (surprise surprise!) caused by a rogue **setState(this.state)** that was being triggered by an event fired in response to a storage subsystem change that happened shortly after I called setState() in the above code.

Ironically I originally used the much maligned **forceUpdate()** to make my component re-render in response to external events. Later on whilst striving, as always, to be a better coder I changed it to setState(this.state) as I kept reading that forceUpdate() is evil and using setState(this.state) is the proper "reactive" way to force a re-render.

Well I'm going back to forceUpdate() now! I will post an update if that causes any problems down the line!